# watir button.enabled? always returns true value

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir

I am doing @browser.some_button(:id => 'some_id').enabled? but it is always returning me the true value even when the button is disabled.

I tried putting sleep for sometime and went and try to see if in the workflow button accidentally gets enabled but it is not.

What might be have gone wrong?

Comment: Please let me know if you need additional info..

Comment: What is the html of the button when it is disabled?

Comment: Here is the html of button when it is disabled..<input type="submit" id="some_id" value="Some_value" class="button is-disabled submit">

Comment: only the class value changes when enabled and disabled gets toggled.When enabled class="button submit"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem**

The Element#enabled? method only checks whether the element has the disabled attribute. It does not check if one of the classes includes the word disabled.

For example, given the html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="submit"id="disabled_id" value="disabled button" disabled>
    <input type="submit" id="enabled_id" value="enabled button">
    <input type="submit" id="some_id" value="Some_value" class="button is-disabled submit"> 
  </body>
</html>
```

You can see that only the first button, which has the disabled attribute, is not enabled:

```
p @browser.button(:id => 'disabled_id').enabled?
#=> false
p @browser.button(:id => 'enabled_id').enabled?
#=> true
p @browser.button(:id => 'some_id').enabled?
#=> true
```

**Solution**

To check if the element is disabled based on a class, you will have to check the class attribute.

Assume the page has the following html, which includes the button in the "disabled" and "enabled" state:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="submit" id="some_id_disabled" value="Some_value" class="button is-disabled submit"> 
    <input type="submit" id="some_id_enabled" value="Some_value" class="button submit"> 
  </body>
</html>
```

One solution would be to check if the element is present when including the class as a locator:

```
p @browser.button(:id => 'some_id_disabled', :class => 'is-disabled').present?
#=> true
p @browser.button(:id => 'some_id_enabled', :class => 'is-disabled').present?
#=> false
```

Alternatively, if you located/stored the element earlier, you could check the class_names instead (rather than re-locating the element):

```
e = @browser.button(:id => 'some_id_disabled')
p e.class_name.split.include?('is-disabled')
#=> true

e = @browser.button(:id => 'some_id_enabled')
p e.class_name.split.include?('is-disabled')
#=> false
```

Comment: Makes Perfect sesnse.Thanks a lot Justin! Appreciate a lot.